# Google Translate: Overcoming cookies obstacle

Tags: google-translate

Seeking guidance to overcome cookie obstacle when invoking:

https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ad.nl%2Fbinnenland%2Fbouterse-tot-20-jaar-cel-veroordeeld-voor-decembermoorden~a89b7e6f%2F

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible by only using a google translate link in this case. The only content is the cookie wall popup and a blurred background image. So the only thing that gets translated is the popup text.

**Workaround**

On google chrome you can accept the cookies and right click on the page and you should have an option to translate the page to English. There should also be a google translate icon in your search bar where you can translate the page.

If you want to send the translated page to someone you could save the web page and send the files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940837/how-to-save-a-webpage-that-gets-translated-to-english-by-google-chrome). The person you sent it to could then open the html file with his/her browser of choice.

Comment: when the company has 1 trillion dollars and cannot unblock the infuriating popup...is the paying customer going to keep paying for being blocked